# NameError: f is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I cant seem to figure out why Python is throwing an error. I'm just a beginner. Code I am using...

```
def integral(startingx,endingx,numberofrectangles):     
    width = (float(endingx) - float(startingx)) / numberofrectangles 
    runningSum = 0     
    for i in range(numberofrectangles):
        height = f(startingx + i*width)
        area = height * width
        runningSum += area
    return runningSum 
print integral (0,1,100)
```

The traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readprint_db.py", line 5, in <module>
    print integral (0,1,100)
  File "readprint_db.py", line 9, in integral
    height = f(startingx + i*width)
NameError: global name 'f' is not defined
```

Not sure how to resolve this.

My apologies I forgot to include the rest of it. This part came before the first portion I posted. Bear with me...

def derivative(f):
    def df(x, h=0.1e-5):
        derive = (f(x+h)-f(x))/h
        return round(deriv,3)
    return df

def derivative(x):
    h = 1./1000.
    rise = f(x+h) - f(x)
    run = h 
    slope = rise / run
    return slope

Edit: Formatting

Comment: So what is `f` supposed to be then? You are using `f()` as a function but don't define it anywhere.

Comment: you never define your f function anywhere, you just called it

Answer (score 2):

I believe you meant to pass the function to integrate as an argument, resulting in a high order function:

```
def integral(f, startingx, endingx, numberofrectangles): # Riemann sum approximation
```